# How to hide caller and calling number on mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, phone-call, telephony

I have the following requirements:

- I have to develop an app both for iOS and for Android.
- In my app, there will be a button "call company" where the user can make a call to a company number.
- If the user pushes the button, the call should be done but the user should not be able to see the number of the company anywhere (calling screen, call history ect.)
- The company should also not see the callers number

To hide the callers number shouldn't be a problem since it can done on every phone manually without any problems. However, is there a way to hide the companys number from the callers screen and call history?

I know it sounds like a strange requirement but maybe there is a way to do this. A workaround would be to call a "proxy" number and forward it to the real companys number, but I'm wondering if it could be done easier.

Comment: basically you can't and should not hide where the user is calling to. User has tpo be able to see where  is your app calling.

Answer (score 1):

You can't on Android.  The ability to directly call is a privlidged operation, you need either to be a system app preinstalled by the OEM or on a rooted phone and jump through some hoops to access it.  THe most you can do is launch the dialer screen with the number pre-inserted.

Pretty much the only way you can come close to this is if you're talking a custom device that your company owns, and not anything released by the app store.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use the Phone app, but you can make a call over the data connection that meets your requirements. You can use a CPaaS provider like Twilio, Vonage, or Plivo to make the call to your company. If you don’t want to use a third party, you can look into using WebRTC to make an audio connection from the app to the agent’s browser.